# Unix redirection of a long-running script

Tags: linux, io-redirection

I've got a cron job that essentially looks like this:

```
*/3 * * * * ruby myscript.rb > /my/location/file.txt
```

myscript.rb essentially looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
sleep(120)
puts "Hello"
```

So every three minutes I'm running a script that runs for two minutes before writing to STDOUT. (In truth, myscript.rb is making a ton of HTTP requests, not sleeping. My suspicion is that it's the time that matters.)

The strange result is that for some percentage of time, /my/location/file.txt is empty.

It *seems* as if the script starts, the file is emptied, and only when the script gets to the end is there data written to the file.

This isn't how *nix redirection works though, right?

Comment: Probably some buffering occurs, and you may want to add some flushing in your script, e.g. `$stdout.flush`

Answer (score 1):

The ruby process is probably just buffering it's output, to set STDOUT to always flush its output, set sync=true for STDOUT:

```
STDOUT.sync = true
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right in that the `file.txt` is truncated as soon as the command is executed.
If you need old contents of the file unless the script will finish the job, you probably need to write to another temporary `file-tmp.txt` and then rename it to `file.txt`.
If you just want to see output as soon as possible, then see @kyle-burton's comment — you need to flush in the script.